# route add -net 192.168.19.0/24 dev tun0 to netplan yaml 1 to 1 mapping

Tags: netplan

as route add is only temporary how can I configure

> sudo route add -net 192.168.19.0/24 dev tun0

into /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [netplan.io examples](https://netplan.io/examples) for route information?  What part of this documentation is lacking, or what issue are you having specifically?

Searching for *route*, I see this example:

```
     routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 9.0.0.1
         metric: 100
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 10.0.0.1
         metric: 100
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 11.0.0.1
         metric: 100
```

You'll have to share your `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` if you want more specifics.